# greenplum spark-connector server.hostEnv not working in k8s

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, greenplum

I am trying to load/write greenplum table via spark-connector, deployed in kubernates;

```
 val gscWriteOptionMap = Map(
  "url" -> "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.95.153:5432/xxx",
  "user" -> "xxx",
  "password" -> "xxxx",
  "dbschema" -> "public",
  "dbtable" -> "test_write",
  "server.port" -> "12900",
  "server.useHostname" -> "false",
  "server.hostEnv" -> "env.NODE_IP"
)

df.write.format("greenplum").options(gscWriteOptionMap).save()
```

greenplum will start a gpfdist server in the spark executor in k8s cluster, having its own ip, which can't be reached by outside;

So, I make executor container to use hostPort:

```
ports:
   - containerPort: 12900
     hostPort: 12900
```

and configured spark-connector to use that port 12900, and it did use;

```
INFO GpfdistService: Successfully started Gpfdist service on 0.0.0.0:12900
```

Also, I configured it to use the node ip as server.hostEnv, (don't know will work or not); but it still use the pod ip for gpfdist;

```
ERROR: connection with gpfdist failed for "gpfdist://10.244.1.45:12900/spark_081bfb94f3667fe1_3d9d854163f8f07a_2_32"
```

10.244.1.45 is the pod ip;

I followed the doc[greenplum spark-connector](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Tanzu-Greenplum-Connector-for-Apache-Spark/2.1/tanzu-greenplum-connector-spark/GUID-options.html). Any help would be appreciated;

Comment: When the connector is configured with the `server.hostEnv` option, it will still fallback to the default behavior of using the IP address returned by `InetAddress.getLocalHost.getHostName`. Are you sure that `NODE_IP` is being exposed as an environment variable inside the pod?

Comment: I tried again, it used the node_ip to create the gpfdist external table. It might be some caching problem at the first place. thanks for your explanation.  Currently it still doesn't work, spark executor on k8s seems not take ports configuration from the template.